# I am working on file writing operations in java.I want to clear the contents of the file, before writing something new in it, How to?

Tags: java, file

I want to clear the contents of the file, before writing into it.I dont want to delete it, I want to clear the contents

Comment: so what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi welcome to stackoverlfow please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please include the code you have tried in your question.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(filename))) {
    pw.println(whatever);
```

this clears/truncates the contents of the file before writing whatever you want to it. This doesn't delete the file.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using PrintWriter using its **print** method and setting content to Empty String.